# pulsing menu items

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu setup with the below css:

```
a.menu:active
    {
        color: #000000;

    }

    a.menu:hover
    {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color:#000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I am looking for a way to make the background color of certain items pulse in and out.

Slow fade from one color to another. Or fade between classes continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Look at pulsate

Comment: You can chain pulsates to make multiple pulses as well.

Answer (score -2):

Look in to adopting a javascript framework such as [jQuery.](http://www.jquery.com)

You will find the `$(selector).animate()` function very useful for this type of thing.

Comment: Thus the jquery tag on my question?